# Control Android TextView visibility run time programmatically

Tags: android, android-widget

In my Java Android application, in run time according to a condition I need to setvisible false in a TextView. How to do it run time programmatically?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You're looking for the `setVisibility` method in `View`.

```
textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

It doesn't take a boolean because you can set it to either Invisible or Gone. If it's Gone, it will not take up any "space" in the layout.

Comment: how to make another control fill the space that "gone" ?? - please important for me \